# making slider images fullscreen

Tags: html, css

I have two problems with my slider.
first, images lack edges inside the frame, I mean the images don't get full screen and are short both horizontally and vertically! I found this code at style.css:

```css
img {
max-width: 100%;
width: auto\9;
height: auto;
}
```

I changed the height value to "100%" and the vertical problem solved but it didn't worked when trying the same on width! as I said I only have problem at slider, I don't know whether there is another section or code special for slider, if there is, please let me know where it is and how it should be changed.
and my second question is how can I change the direction of slider movement? for example content (images) would be moved from left to right instead of right to left!

thanks

Comment: can you try increasing the width of parent div of img tag?

Comment: There are 2 obvious things that must be provided in your question before any useful answer could be made. 1. what type of image is it? Is it abstract like something that aspect ratio isn't a concern? Or is the image of something that shouldn't be stretched? 2. The slider is a definite factor involving the images' dimensions. So post the slider's HTML and CSS and include the url(s) of a real image you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 9);
  height: auto;
 }
```